# Name the 25 Ants

Tags: word, wordplay

When solving the [Contagious Ants on a Meterstick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/contagious-ants-on-a-meterstick) problem, puzzlers often overlook the fact that ants are sophisticated creatures with names, dreams, and personalities.

1. `_ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is an expert navigator, and is especially skilled in the presence of celestial bodies.
2. `_ (_) _ _ _ _` is always taking back sworn testiony.
3. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _ _` is the oddball ant of the bunch. She always seems out of place.
4. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _` is magical and makes powerful weapons.
5. `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _` is the poorest and lowliest ant.
6. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _` always gets things done right this second.
7. `_ _ _ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is the best at following orders and instructions.
8. `_ _ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is a chemist, and she also has a fondness for fissile material.
9. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` is the most stubborn ant of the bunch. She always defies authority.
10. `_ _ _ _ (_) _ _ _ _` is always deeply sorry and committed to changing her ways.
11. `_ _ _ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is the most consequential and influential ant.
12. `_ _ _ _ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is always poring over the books, mindful of the bottom line.
13. `_ _ _ (_) _ _ _` is an expert at keeping temperatures low.
14. `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` is forever interviewing for employment.
15. `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` has the most opulent, pampered lifestyle of all the ants.
16. `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _` is the most chivalrous ant, and aspires to be a knight.
17. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _ _` is actually a wild fowl disguised to *look* like an ant.
18. `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` is larger-than-life grandiose. Always bigger and better for this ant!
19. `_ (_) _ _ _ _ _` is homeless, forever wandering the streets.
20. `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _ _` smells. :(
21. `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _` is forever trying to overthrow people to take their place.
22. `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _ _` is by far the biggest ant, and she looks a little gray.

But wait! There are still three ants left!

**Can you take all the circled letters, unscramble them, and determine the names of the three ants I missed?**

*Please include the answers to the 22 clues along with your solution.*

Comment: Would #16 be aspiring to the life of a wandering, roving knight, perchance?

Comment: @DamienH: A pleasant gallivanting ant shan't wind up a mendicant. ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> 1. sex(t)ant
>  2. r(e)cant
>  3. a(b)errant
>  4. e(n)chant
>  5. pe(a)sant
>  6. i(n)stant
>  7. compl(i)ant
>  8. reac(t)ant
>  9. r(e)calcitrant
>  10. repe(n)tant
>  11. impor(t)ant
>  12. accoun(t)ant
>  13. coo(l)ant
>  14. (a)pplicant
>  15. (l)uxuriant
>  16. (g)allant
>  17. p(h)easant
>  18. ex(t)ravagant
>  19. v(a)grant
>  20. fr(a)grant
>  21. (s)upplant
>  22. (e)lephant

These leave us with the letters

> TEBNANITENTTLALGHTAASE

Which anagram into

> HESITANT, BLATANT, ELEGANT

Comment: Welp, everyone beat me to it.

Comment: Glad you beat me. I would have spent ages trying to solve the anagrams with my incorrect answers.

Comment: I spent awhile trying to work out the anagrams with a couple of wrong answers. It was not super fun. :)

Comment: All correct, and the correct three names too. I tip my hat to you, sir.

Comment: i didn't even get that all of the words should end in ant. one of the reasons i don't try to solve these types of puzzles, although i think they are fascinating. congrats on trusted user status!