# words ending with ant

Tags: word

Find the words ends with " ANT " clues given

What kind of an ant works with figures? An accountANT.

1. Lives in the jungle?
2. Is far away?
3. Is extraordinarily large?
4. Works for a master?
5. Is good-natured?
6. Is unchanging?
7. Is luxurious?
8. Is one who takes part?
9. Is a very small child?
10. Is sleeping?
11. Is very bright?
12. Is empty?
13. Is immediate?
14. Is plentiful?
15. Has moved to a diferent country?
16. Is meaningful?
17. Is something that grows?
18. Has infuence over others?
19. Is unsure and indecisive?
20. Lives in a certain place?

Comment: Some overlap with http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/name-the-25-ants.

Comment: I think a fun twist on a puzzle like this would be to not say what all the answers had in common, just to give the questions and maybe a hint that they have something in common, and let people figure it out.

Comment: Hm, funny thing that nearly all have elephant for 1. African elephants normally dont live in the jungle...(more than 90% of all elephants are african, asian elephants and forest elephants have only a small population)

Answer (score 7):

> Lives in the jungle? - ELEPHANT, PLANT, ANT
>  Is far away? - DISTANT
>  Is extraordinarily large? - GIANT
>  Works for a master? - SERVANT
>  Is good-natured? - PLEASANT
>  Is unchanging? - CONSTANT
>  Is luxurious? - ELEGANT, EXTRAVAGANT
>  Is one who takes part? - PARTICIPANT
>  Is a very small child? - INFANT
>  Is sleeping? - DORMANT
>  Is very bright? - BRILLIANT
>  Is empty? - VACANT
>  Is immediate? - INSTANT
>  Is plentiful? - ABUNDANT
>  Has moved to a different country? - IMMIGRANT
>  Is meaningful? - SIGNIFICANT
>  Is something that grows? - PLANT
>  Has influence over others? - DOMINANT
>  Is unsure and indecisive? - HESITANT
>  Lives in a certain place? - INHABITANT

Comment: I would consider Extravagant for 7.

Answer (score 2):

1. Elephant
   2.distant
   4.Servant
   8.participant
   18.dominant
   14.abundant
   15.Migrant

   6. Constant
      7.elegant
      9.infant

Answer (score 2):

1)elephant 2)distant 3)exorbitant/giant 4)assistant 5)pleasant/tolerant 6)constant 7)luxuriant/elegant/extravagant 8)participant/contestant 9)infant 10)dormant 11)radiant/ luminary 12)vacant 13)instant 14)abundant 15)migrant/immigrant 16)relevant/significant 17)plant 18)dominant/ important 19)hesitant 20)occupant/habitant

Answer (score 0):

1. Elephant
2. Distant
3. Giant
4. Servant
5. Tolerant
6. Constant
7. Extravagant
8. Participant
9. Infant
10. Dormant
11. Luminant
12. Vacant
13. Instant
14. Abundant
15. Migrant
16. Relevant
17. Plant
18. Dominant
19. Hesitant
20. Habitant

Answer (score -1):

6 constant
12 vacant
15 migrant
14 abundant
13 instant

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  These solutions have already been given in another answer, so this answer is somewhat redundant, but keep looking through the questions and I'm sure you'll find other questions you can answer.